# How do I detect if a web page is rendered dynamically from Javascript in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am building a web scraper that has to retrieve quickly the text of a web page, from HTML only. I'm using Python, `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.
I would like to detect if the web page content is pure HTML or if it's rendered from Javascript. In this last case, I would just return an error message saying that this cannot be done.

I know about headless browsers to render the Javascript but in this case I really just need to detect it the fastest way possible without having to render it.

It's not really possible to detect `script` tag as there are many in every webpage and that doesn't mean the text content is rendered in Javascript necessarily.

Is there something I could check jn the HTML that tells me accurately that the body content will be rendered from Javascript?

Thank you

Comment: No. Javascript does not need a placeholder to modify the HTML. There's nothing in the HTML that signals that it *will* be changed by Javascript.

Comment: But if you're scraping a given website, you know if it's dynamically generated (with React, Angular, etc) or if it's made of static pages. Why would you have to _detect_ that? You just have to visit the website once and try with JS disabled, you'll know.

Comment: @JeremyThille Not sure I understand what you mean. I'm scraping any website. Do you mean that I will know by detecting that the html body is empty for example?

Comment: How can you scrape "any" website? Are you just loading random websites? What are you looking for on them if they are random?

Comment: @JeremyThille That's my use case. I am making a program that will be used to gather some key information on any given website. So it's really large scraping where I don't need to be specific. I just need the text content, or to return an error if the content is javascript rendered.

Comment: Ah, I get it. But I don't see how you can detect if it's dynamically generated. Besides, it can be _partially_ generated. The search bar can very well be static, but the results list can very well be fetched with Ajax and generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the initial DOM that shows beforehand that the site is rendered with js. These are some stuff you could try:

- Analyzing several websites and make a guess on where the site
  is rendered with js based on the page's content size.
- You could also get the html of different pages of the site
  and compare the content length (for a js-rendered site, the contents
  of different pages are likely to be the same/similar before any code is executed).
- Check the content size of the scripts or detect the scripts names of
  famous technologies like react, vue and angular